# Old website (2002) to new website (2014)

Tags: web, seo, mobile-website, friendly-url

One of my main concerns is about **SEO**, when I have the intention to completely redesign a website and make it work on a mobile device.

Following that idea, I have been researching on [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/smartphone-sites/) and have decided choose the first option "Responsive Design"

**CURRENT SITUATION**

1. Made in TABLE
2. **SEO** based only in KEYWORDS and DESCRIPTION
3. URL not friendly
4. Use the first version HTML
5. Layout old-fashioned
6. Excellent position in the GOOGLE Rank
7. Excellent traffic visitors

**TARGET**

1. Create mobile version to attend target group which use mobile device
2. Full redesign, including best practices organic SEO Friendly URL
3. HTML5
4. CCS3
5. Responsive Design
6. New technology JSP to PHP (Laravel 4)

**OBSERVATION**

Because this site has been online since 2002, it has developed an excellent position on GOOGLE. The biggest concern of all, is to lose the position because of the migration to the new version. Im Seeking alternative or more efficient solution, I'v identified the use of 301 redirect to the new URL.

My Questions are as follows:

If the domain of the website is maintained, will this change only the URL?

example:

**From**

www.website.com/cs/detail.jsp?id=123456

www.website.com/aboutus.html

**To**

www.website.com./product/detail/123456/lorem-ipsum-dolem-sit-amet

www.website.com/about-us

Following that thought, I'v found some solutions like 301 redirect.

**DOUBT 01**

I will use the 301 redirect to each page, then will I have to put that 301 redirect one-to-one?

aboutus.html

```
response.setStatus(301);
response.setHeader( “Location”, “http://www.website.com/about-us” );
response.setHeader( “Connection”, “close” );
```

cs/detail.jsp

```
response.setStatus(301);
response.setHeader( “Location”, “http://www.website.com./product/detail/123456/lorem-ipsum-dolem-sit-amet” );
response.setHeader( “Connection”, “close” );
```

**DOUBT 02**

Following the doubt above, will i have to put the new website in sub folder?

Example:

```
|public_html
|-index.html
|-quemsomos.html
|-cs
|--detalhe.jsp
|-novo-site
|--index.php
```

And will the URL will be just like that of:

www.website.com/**new-website**/quem-somos

www.website.com/**new-website**/product/detail/123456/lorem-ipsum-dolem-sit-amet

**DOUBT 03**

Is there anything else i need to worry about?

Answer (score 2):

**Answer 1:**

Its better to redirect the entire site using a `.htaccess` file rather than writing it in every single page. You can refer to my link below that will help you gain an understanding of this redirection.

**Answer 2:**

The **URL** strictly follows your directory structure.

**Answer 3:**

The search engines will take some time to discover the **301**, recognize it, and credit the new page with the rankings and trust of its predecessor. This process can be lengthier if search engine spiders rarely visit the given web page, or if the new **URL** doesn't properly resolve.

You may refer to the link below to gain a better understanding about the 301 redirection.

[how to 301 redirect](http://www.howto301redirect.com/)